# Rselenium error...trying to click Show More on a Google Scholar Page

Tags: r, rselenium

I am using rvest and Rselenium to scrape Google Scholar page. I am working on the example provided in http://www.r-bloggers.com/google-scholar-scraping-with-rvest-package/.
Using RSelenium, I want to click the "Show more" button on the Google Scholar Page to get a list of all publications.
The code chunk I am running is

```
library(RSelenium)

checkForServer()

startServer()

remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4444
                      , browserName = "firefox"
                      )

remDr$open()

remDr$getStatus()

remDr$navigate("https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=sTR9SIQAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao")

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".gs_lbl")

webElem$clickElement()
```

Where .gs_lbl is the css selector fr Show more and in the last step I am trying to send a click to it.
However it results in the below error:

Error:   Summary: ElementNotVisible
     Detail: An element command could not be completed because the element is not visible on the page.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException
>

I also used selector gadget to verify that .gs_lbl is the CSS selector for Show More...so I am unsure how to proceed here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're not familiar already, the `scholar` package on CRAN might be helpful for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, I just needed one modification to click on the "Show More" button correctly. The correct selector is `"#gsc_bpf_more"`, and so the second-last line of your code should read:

`webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#gsc_bpf_more")`